# Exchange 2010 Signature Policy per group

Tags: exchange-2010

We are about to implement a signature policy on Exchange 2010, and we'd like to know if it is possible to implement a different policy to different groups in AD.

Is this possible? The examples that I found use this:

-FromMemberOf ‘All Users’

Can we just change that 'All Users' to something like 'Sales Reps' *A group in AD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to do this with Transport Rules you can do it like this:

http://www.theemailadmin.com/2010/01/how-to-add-automatic-email-signatures-and-disclaimers-with-exchange-2010/

For the Condition in Step 1 of the rule you could change it to be "from a member of a Distribution List" instead of just a generic all user one.

You could also look at third party add-ons.  Exclaimer is a pretty good one, it will run on Exchange Server 2010 and lets you configure different signatures based on group membership, OU membership, will automatically pull details from AD (eg names, phone numbers) and a host of other features.  I've worked with it before and found it to be good.